# Alpine JS: Bind the label of a select menu to a hidden input

Tags: alpine.js

I am attempting to submit both the value and label of a select field in a form. How can I retrieve the value of the selected option and use it to populate the value of a hidden input? Here is the relevant code snippet (I understand it won't work, just trying to show how I'd like it to work in my head):

```html
<div x-data="{ color: '' }">
  <select x-model="color">
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Orange</option>
    <option value="3">Yellow</option>
  </select>

  <input type="hidden" x-bind:value="color.value">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy to do that.

```html
<div x-data="{ color: ''}">
  <select x-model="color">
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Orange</option>
    <option value="3">Yellow</option>
  </select>

  <input type="hidden" x-bind:value="color">
</div>
```

Note that although the select may look like it has a value, it doesn't upon initial page load. If you instantly were to submit, the value of `color` would remain to whatever you set it as default. In that case it would be better to set `color: '1'`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. That's still ending the label for me unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean with "ending"? When I tried this, it worked perfectly to set the value for the hidden input.

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. I dropped the code in as is; the value of the hidden input is still being set to the label of the dropdown (red, orange, yellow).

Comment: Well, I thought that's what you wanted?

Comment: No - I want the value of the dropdown to populate the hidden input, not the label.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want that, but anyhow, I've updated my answer.